# Hibernate Criteria taking off associations

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a class Usuario. User have association with UsuarioPerfil:

```
public class Usuario{

  /*Attributes*/

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario_perfil", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_usuario_id_usuario_perfil"))
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private UsuarioPerfil usuarioPerfil;

  }

  public class UsuarioPerfil{

    /*Attributes*/
  }
```

I am performing queries using the Criteria, as follows:

```
  Session sessao = this.getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
  sessao.createCriteria(Usuario.class).list();
```

However, in some cases wish list does not come in the data UsuarioPerfil entity, only the User. How can I accomplish this using Hibernate Criteria?

Note: I know this is possible using Hibernate or JPA Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can explicitly do what you are asking with the Hibernate Criteria API because it is generally accepted practice to make associations `LAZY` and set them to `EAGER` on a case-by-case basis.

Therefore, change your mapping to use `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` and then in the cases where you need the association in your query, specify it as:

```
criteria.setFetchMode("usuarioPerfil", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

If you have access to JPA's `EntityGraph` annotations, I would strongly suggest you look into those as well.  At a minimum, you can at least look at Hibernate's `FetchProfile` concept because those go along way to defining fetch strategies by name which helps keep code and queries much cleaner.

Comment: Many thanks @Naros, it worked perfectly. It was just what I was looking for.